# How do you quit during hero selection?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yes, I know it gives me a 5-minute penalty before I can try to join another lobby, and that it's a horrible unsportsmanlike thing to do.

But the only way I can figure out how to do it is to close the entire application and re-launch.  Is there no better way to quit a lobby than this?

(I'm trying to play with a friend and the chat system is down, so every 5 minutes we're joining at the same time in hopes that we get lucky...)

Comment: Note: You can invite friends by name if you know it by typing it in the box at the top right of the invite screen.  No more queue dodging :D

Comment: Yup. You don't need to chat to play with friends.

Comment: @StrixVaria -- you're my hero! I've always been really frustrated when chat was down and I wanted to play with roommates!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way to quit champion selection is to close the game. The idea of a queue dodging button has been brought up many times on the forums, and [has been shut down by Riot](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=8026154#post8026154) because they don't want people to queue dodge so it's not gonna change any time soon.

Do note that the time penalty for queue dodging [goes up if you do it repeatedly](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Queue_dodging#Penalties) in a single day. The time penalties for dodging a Ranked game are also significantly more severe.